# Closure property of a set of linear transformations under composition

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, linear-transformations

Let us define a set of linear transformations $S =\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & a\\ 0&1&b\\ 0 & 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Consider performing these transformations along an arbitrary axis, we also define $\hat S = \{r^{-1}sr\ |\ r\in SO(3), s\in S\}$.

I noticed that $\hat S$ is **not** closed under composition. We can check that for any $x,y\in \hat S$, $tr(x) = tr(r^{-1}sr)= tr(s) =3$ but $tr(xy) \not\equiv 3$. Thus, $\hat S\neq \hat S^2$.

I am wondering whether $\hat S^n$ converges to a subset, i.e. whether $\hat S^n = \hat S^{n+1}$ for some $n>0$ ?

What's more, $\hat S^n \subseteq SL_3(\mathbb R)$ since $\det x = 1,\ \forall x\in \hat S$. It seems $S^* = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} \hat S^i$ is a subgroup of $SL_3(\mathbb R)$. But does $S^* = SL_3(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I mentioned $tr(xy) \neq 3$ to show there exist $x,y\in \hat S$, such that $xy\not\in \hat S$, so that $\hat S$ is not closed under composition. The $x,y\in \mathbb R$ was a slight abuse of notation (edited now). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, I meant $tr(xy)\neq 3$ for $x,y\in \hat S$ but not $x,y\in S$. Consider $x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 1& b\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ a & 1 & 0 \\ b & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Both of them belong to $\hat S$ according to the definition, but $tr(xy) = 3 + ab$.

Comment: And how is $y\in \hat{S}$? What $r$ did you use?

Comment: @DietrichBurde $r = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $u = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -b\\ 0 & 1 & -a \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $r^{-1}u r = y$. (The intuition is to rotate $x$ axis to $z$ axis, perform a transformation in $S$, and then rotate back.)